# Incorrect news feed in the Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, feed

I am trying to fetch the news feed of a Facebook account using Facebook's graph API.

Facebook's graph API is returning only the data of last day and not older then that.

I have gone through the Facebook API explorer and tried the same over there as well - but I'm still unable to get the data.

How can I get this data?

Comment: Please post the query you are trying to fetch with.

Comment: Yeah, when I try it I get posts from last month

Comment: I tried the following URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?limit=25&access_token=<<access token>>

Comment: My access token has all the permissions basic as well as advanced (including offline access)

Comment: Did you try setting the limit at 5000 or querying without it?

Comment: yes , but it didn't worked as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the a FQL query to get the closest result. The aggregation generated by Facebook for the user will not be returned which explains why the result don't return exactly the same as the view on Facebook NewsFeed.

Additionally, the "AND is_hidden = 0" will avoid to return hidden stories.

SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0

You need the read_stream permission to do this.
You can also stop asking for offline_access as it's being deprecated (https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/05/02/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/)